# Unable to read formula related to other sheet using closedxml

Tags: c#, .net, closedxml

I am reading excel steam and converting it to a workbook using closedxml. The workbook has 2 sheets. The first sheet has a cell that has a formula that references the second sheet. When i read to read this cell, i get an exception. Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an expected behaviour?

No.